# Woocommerce My-account order details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Can anyone help me how to display recent order when the order is completed,Right now I an getting completed,cancelled,processing,onhold how can i display only completed purchases...

Answer (score 2):

You can do a loop like this to get all the completed orders.

```
$orders = get_posts( array (
                            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
                            'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
                            )
                   );
             foreach ($orders as $order)
            {
                $order_wc = new WC_Order( $order->ID );
                var_dump($order);
            }
```